# Unable to execute string in powershell

Tags: powershell, windows-installer, uninstallation, powershell-4.0

somescript.ps1 will return a string which is a command

```
$PATHS = @("HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall", "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall") $SOFTWARE = "Microsoft Azure Information Protection" ForEach ($path in $PATHS) { $installed = Get-ChildItem -Path $path | ForEach { Get-ItemProperty $_.PSPath } | Where-Object { $_.DisplayName -match $SOFTWARE } | Select-Object -Property DisplayName,DisplayVersion,UninstallString ForEach ($app in $installed) { Write-Output "$($app.UninstallString)"} }
```

Now, I have a command which is a string returns from above query as below:

```
PS D:\FolderName> .\somescript.ps1
"C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{21b41fEE-93c0-498f-a284-659d275b4076}\AzInfoProtection.exe"  /uninstall
MsiExec.exe /I{7FA8B359-E9D7-4037-8DE3-A28F2603D743}
```

I need to execute the above returned string which is a command in PowerShell

> "C:\ProgramData\Package
> Cache{21b41fEE-93c0-498f-a284-659d275b4076}\AzInfoProtection.exe"
> /uninstall
> MsiExec.exe /I{7FA8B359-E9D7-4037-8DE3-A28F2603D743}

I am getting errors like below

PS C:\ProgramData\Package Cache> C:\ProgramData\Package Cache{21b41fEE-93c0-498f-a284-659d275b4076}\AzInfoProtection.exe  /uninstall MsiExec.exe /I{7FA8B359-E9D7-4037-8DE3-A28F2603D743}

```
C:\ProgramData\Package : The term 'C:\ProgramData\Package' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or
operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{21b41fEE-93c0-498f-a284-659d275b4076}\A ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\ProgramData\Package:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

How to fix the command to execute this in PowerShell ?

Comment: Try it with single quotes

Comment: can you post the complete command

Comment: Can you post the contents of `somescript.ps1`. You pass the string `"C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{21b41fEE-93c0-498f-a284-659d275b4076}\AzInfoProtection.exe"` which is a command from what I understand, and then some other args? I think that you don't escape the command and the space 
in `Package Cache` is causing trouble. It would be helpful if you show what you want to do in the `somescript.ps1`.

Comment: $PATHS = @("HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall",
           "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall")
$SOFTWARE = "Microsoft Azure Information Protection"

ForEach ($path in $PATHS) {
    $installed = Get-ChildItem -Path $path |
                 ForEach { Get-ItemProperty $_.PSPath } |
                 Where-Object { $_.DisplayName -match $SOFTWARE } |
                 Select-Object -Property DisplayName,DisplayVersion,UninstallString

    ForEach ($app in $installed) {
       Write-Output "$($app.UninstallString)"}
}